# mailto: links not opening mail app on Android in cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

This is driving me crazy. I'm working on a Ionic app (Cordova, Angular etc). I have a contact us link which contains a mailto: href

```
href="mailto:info@somedomain.net?subject=my%20App"
```

I've read countless posts on SO that say you have to remove

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

from the config.xml in the project root and replace it with:

```
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="true" />
```

Which I've done. When I run `ionic build` it gets added to the config.xml in `platforms/android/res/xml`. But no matter what I do the link doesn't open the mail app on any Android simulator (even when email is configured in the simulator).

Sadly I don't have a device to test on - so is this just a emulator thing or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you try adding inAppBrowser plugin and set the target to _system

Comment: if you're using latest version of cordova, maybe you have to configure CSP in your html?

Comment: I did not replace <access origin="*"/> but put it right after <access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="true" />, which works well for my case

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You must install the [cordova plugin whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist):

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

or if you want to save the reference to your **config.xml** file:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist --save
```

and that you have to add the intent to your **config.xml** file:

```
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
```

You can find more info [here](http://devgirl.org/2015/04/24/apache-cordova-newsflash/).

Comment: @bagusflyer: same rule apply.

Comment: when I try this approach with cordova 6.4.0 and cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 on android 5.0, I end up with popup saying "Unsupported action -- this actions is not currently supported"

Comment: @Peter: I think things might have changed now. I haven't used the latest cordova version so cannot be much help. Cheers.

Comment: Indeed. Nothing on this page worked for me except the simple swap of window.open('mailto:xxxx') to window.location.href='mailto:xxxx")

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
window.location.href = "mailto:your@ema.il?subject=Works on iOS too";
```

Comment: OMG. I tried EVERYTHING else on this page, this, THIS is what worked for me. So simple. Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Actually this one worked well for me too.

Answer (score 5):

I just solved this thanks to the responses & articles above.  I'm not sure what has or hasn't changed since the above postings, but for the reference of others; I now have `http://, https://, tel:, & mailto:` working with only the [inappbrowser](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html) plugin installed and no manual edits to config.xml needed.  I did everything mentioned above & it still wasn't working, so I started fiddling and found that I the `window.open()` call requires the second parameter of `"_system"` to work correctly (it tried to use the browser and "navigate" to `http://mailto:xxx...` without the `"_system"` flag).

However, for curiousity's sake, I uninstalled the whitelist plugin and removed the manual edits in config.xml and it still works.

Notes:

-I don't remember all the variations I tried, but onclick couldn't access the Ionic/Angular/Cordova scope(s), so I stuck with ng-click.

-I did not / have not tried using href="..." with any of the options. 
(If I remember, I'll test them and update this to reflec my results.)

So, with *only* the cordova-plugin-inappbrowser installed and *no* config.xml edits, here are my working / tested solutions:

```
ng-click="window.open('http://somesite.com', '_system')"
ng-click="window.open('https://google.com', '_system')"
ng-click="window.open('tel:(123) 345-4567')"
ng-click="window.open('mailto:email@example.com', '_system')"
```

Tested 9/20/2016 Using:

HTC One M8, android 6 ,cordova v6.3.1, cordova-plugin-inappbrowser v1.5.0, ionic v2.0.0, jdk1.8.0_101, android SDKs 21, 23, & 24 installed

Answer (score 3):

what if you replace "true" with "yes"... I use this in my app and it works.

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

Comment: I really thought that would fix it, sadly it doesn't. Does your link work in the emulator? As thats whats I'm testing on...

Comment: It does work for me in an emulator. Have you updated to the latest version of cordova and android?  (cordova 5.0.0, android 4.0.0.)  I had to update my project in order to get it to work.

Comment: Correction, it doesn't work for me in my emulator..It returns with the error "This action is not supported."  I tested a phone number initially, and it worked. I just tested an e-mail on my phone (droid turbo, openned the email in "Inbox") though, and it worked

Comment: Thanks Dave - will test on a device before update cordova as it looks like it breaks a few things with ionic. If it works I'll mark as correct.

Comment: No luck on device. Nightmare.

Comment: I downgraded my app to android@3.7.1 just to test it and it stopped working. I think upgrading might fix your issue.

Comment: My device is running 5+ - question for you, is your app running with crosswalk, starting to think that could be the issue...

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this today and noticed something that affected mailto, but not tel, links:

In addition to adding the intent to the cordova config as described by dave's answer

`<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />`

I also had to allow mailto links in the csp header of my page

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' mailto:*">`

Didn't see any documentation around this behaviour of CSP headers.

Answer (score 2):

Just in addition to use [Cordova's WhiteListPlugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) ;

It worked for me in this way:
**in config.xml**

```
<access origin="*"/>
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="true" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

**And specially for ios add :**

```
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-navigation href="mailto:*" launch-external="yes"/>    
    ...
 <platform name="ios">
```

Answer (score 0):

Altering [Cordova's WhiteListPlugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) in `config.xml` did not work for me -- `<access >,``. I tried many combinations, including those above. Doesn't mean these won't work necessarily, just for my setup it doesn't.  (Building for Browser, Android, and iOS)

However, using the [Cordova InAppBrowser Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) worked:

**As mentioned above,  use the inAppBrowser plugin and set the target to _system.**

This by passes the issues I was seeing in iOS with `unsupported url`, and launches the native systems web browser (i.e., Does not rely on WhiteListPlugin to allow the URL call).

Hope this helps.

Cordova version 6.3.1.